# javascript : Identify the form in the loop after submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a loop that creates 4 forms in the view And I put a button for each form to submit the form? What solution would you suggest to find out which form was submitted?
Html :

```
@foreach (var item in 4){
<form id="Form_ImgGallery" method="post">
    <div class="box_galleryimg col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">                       
        <input type="file" class="form-control">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input  type="submit" class="btn btn-info waves-effect" value="upload">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

}

Comment: Give a name to a buttons then when you click on the button get the button name but you have to make a pattern when you give a button name. like button1, button2, button3 ...

Comment: Dont use submit buttons, use normal buttons with onclick. In on click call a function with identifier and then you can do what you want

Comment: While that would work, it violates WCAG guidelines so it not really a workable solution. In addition all `form` elements should have a `submit` button so that they still work even with client-side JS disabled.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Which solution has high performance??

Comment: You're looping through 4 elements in the DOM - performance isn't really an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should give each of the forms a different id. and then via id you can find out which form was submitted. here is a sample for getting idea.

```
const form = document.querySelector("#Form_ImgGallery");
form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.attributes.id.value);  //Form_ImgGallery
});
```

Comment: 1) If you have to manually give every `form` a unique `id`, then you have to copy/paste this exact event handler N times, which is not DRY and a pain to maintain 2) If the forms already have a unique id applied to them *before* runtime, then you already know what the id will be at runtime, so the JS function becomes almost entirely redundant.

Comment: I see your point. I was just thinking about how to get the ID for which form was submited. 1) for giving each form a uniqe id you can use the index, like id=``Form_ImgGallery${index}``, instead of setting all id's manually (just for clarifying). 2) But I saw your answer and thats a good approach. keep up the good work.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is that your loop is creating multiple elements with the same `id`, which is invalid. Within a single page, there can be no duplication of `id`. If you want to group elements, then use a `class`. This is what I've done in the example below.

From there you can use the `this` keyword in the event handler to refer to the specific `form` element which raised the `submit` event, and get information from it, or one of the form fields it contains.

```js
$('.Form_ImgGallery').on('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the form submitting in this example
  let $form = $(e.target);
  let file = $form.find('input[type="file"]').val();
  console.log(file);
});

/* plain JS version:
document.querySelectorAll('.Form_ImgGallery').forEach(form => {
  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the form submitting in this example
    let file = e.target.querySelector('input[type="file"]').value;
    console.log(file);
  });
});
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="Form_ImgGallery" method="post">
  <div class="box_galleryimg col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input type="file" class="form-control">
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info waves-effect">upload</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<form class="Form_ImgGallery" method="post">
  <div class="box_galleryimg col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input type="file" class="form-control">
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info waves-effect">upload</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<form class="Form_ImgGallery" method="post">
  <div class="box_galleryimg col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input type="file" class="form-control">
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info waves-effect">upload</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<form class="Form_ImgGallery" method="post">
  <div class="box_galleryimg col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input type="file" class="form-control">
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info waves-effect">upload</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```